# How to avoid memory leaks, with C++ with STL containers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

code snippet below:

```
//container declared
map<string, structA*>& aMap;

// allocation and insertion to container
structA *item = new structA();
aMap["arrDevAddr"] = item;
```

However I iterate and free the map value (pointer) at the end of the map getting used.

Now, due to above code snippet, valgrind is flagging me as "definitely leaked" message.

I want to clarify, the general principle of coding to avoid memory leak. As per my understanding, in (C++ coding):

1. when we allocate a memory, we are entitled to free it aswell, limted by the overall span of code.
2. when we keep the allocated memory in some container (e.g. map here), we still need to retain those pointers (allocations), until the map is using those pointers.
3. which means, allocate >> add pointer to container >> usage of pointers in the map >> ensure "deleting/freeing" the struct-pointers, when the map use is over, or if the map is contained in some object, then in the object's "destructor", map should be iterated and struct-pointers should be freed.

correct me, if I am wrong in my understanding.

**SECOND CASE:**

```
class A{
...
map<string, structA*>& aMap;
...
}
```

now in some other class, the map is inserted with value as;

```
 if(..)
{ structA item;
     aObj->aMap["arrDevAddr"] = &item;
}
...
```

Now, in this case, as "item" is local to the scope, will the map be containing the "dangling references"? If not, how?
In such scenario's what should be the way to ensure, we avoid any memory-leaks while coding?

Comment: Don't manage the memory yourself. Use a smart pointer or Boost's ptr containers.

Comment: Or store values, not pointers to other things.

Comment: _"How to avoid memory leaks"_ The easiest way is simply not to use `new`! The [c++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) arms you with all the stuff necessary to realize this.

Comment: use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr.

Comment: Don't put pointers into containers unless you absolutely have to. And if you have to either store a pointer to the actual object stored in a different container or else put the pointer in a smart pointer.

Comment: @Galik What's the downside of storing a smart pointer; besides its overhead?

Comment: @Carcigenicate nothing really. also, the overhead is very little to non, so you shouldn't be concerned about it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The downside of smart pointers compared with storing the objects themselves (without pointers) is that even smart pointers can be dangling references. In recent testing I could not measure a difference in speed between raw pointers and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Galik: They cannot be dangling references unless you did something very, very wrong. That's the whole point of smart pointers.

Comment: @Puppy You're right. What I meant to say was "null references", which can be both good and bad in different situations.

Comment: definitely "smart-pointers" or the "unique_ptr" are the ways to avoid memory-leaks in such instances. However, refreshing the basics, wanted to understand the scenario, as to how this prone to memory-leak. "Call by value", seems to be answer to my query. Thanks "juanchopanza", thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Don't `delete` or `free` things yourself. Always use a memory-managing class- these are completely immune to memory leaks and such related problems unless you work very hard to do something very stupid.

In this case something like `unique_ptr` would be fine, or even just storing `structA` by value.

Comment: Neither did you provide a suitable learning example. Frankly, the OP seems perfectly capable of substituting a template parameter into a Standard template- he just did it with the map.

Comment: I have seen below, and it was quite correct and your example is completely unsuitable for a learner to try to learn from. Or for much of anything else, really.

Comment: Compilable example is far from the only relevant criterion. Although if you're going to make one, making one that actually resembles good practice is a good start.

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer using your sockpuppet? Who are you talking to?

Answer (score 0):

You would avoid memory leaks by storing a std::unique_ptr rather than a raw pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct structA {};
using structA_ptr = std::unique_ptr<structA>;

//container declared
std::map<std::string, structA_ptr> aMap;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    aMap.emplace("bob", structA_ptr { new structA {} });

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but I felt compelled to downvote you for the global mutable variable and the terrible redundant opaque typedef.

Comment: @Puppy The global won't be leaking when it is destructed though. But that is not the right idea.

Comment: I felt compelled to upvote you for a good answer, rather than making up nonsense criticisms that betray only jealousy and/or spite.